# Mouse Hover to activate another div

Tags: html, css, hover

I got these two divs.

I need the second div (blue) pops up when the first div(red) hover it's activated, now it appears only if the pointer touch the hidden second div.

http://codepen.io/IvanPalma/pen/XXpwoW?editors=110

```css
.first-div { 
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.second-div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  opacity:0;
}
.second-div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  opacity:0;
}

.second-div:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
<div class="second-div">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your last selector to:

```
.first-div:hover > .second-div {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```css
.first-div { 
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.second-div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  opacity:0;
}
.second-div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  opacity:0;
}

.first-div:hover > .second-div {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
<div class="second-div">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because in your css code, you say that you want to make the second div visible when your mouse hovers over the second div.
 I believe you want that to pop up when you hover over the first div right?
 If so, change .second-div:hover to .first-div:hover